# Angular routing after authentication

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Actually I am struggling for correct routing after successful login authentication in complex web app on Angular js 2. I am following following link:

```
https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-authentication-sample
```

I make understand code but the issue is after successful login if I again change url to /login in again takes me to login screen where I have login form, but my concern is why I have been redirected to login screen although I know current code do so but how can I resolve this and achieve navigation in correct way.

Please help that what is the correct way to achieve the same.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not only on a third-party site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside login add a condition to check if `id_token` is present in localstorage and it is not undefined. If it is present navigate the user to home by using `this.router.navigate(['home']);`

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming** you are using a token (like jwt) and **localstorage**, you can do something like this:

```
  //This could be different, but you must save somewhere the token.
    // It will depend on your startegy
// For example, when loggin in, you may save it on localstorage:
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user)); // just an example. 

    //THEN, you can redirect using the router
    this.router.navigate(['yourRoute']);
```

Hope that can help you! Please, tell me if you want a more detail example.